# Memory not released after removing subviews (ARC)

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to solve "Received Memory Warning" issue.

My app has 2 view controllers and when you click a button on first view controller,
detail view controller appears.
The detail view controller has a view inherited of UIView called 'topView' and the view has many subviews.
The subviews are also inherited of UIView and each subview has 2 UILabels.

My question is when you go back to first view controller by clicking back button,
'topView' is not released, even if I put the following code in viewDidDisappear.

How can I release the memory of topView?

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    [[self.topView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    self.topView= nil;    
}
```

Am I missing some thing?
I think I'm heading to some wrong direction, so please give me advice.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the right object when you say that it's not being released? Run Instruments on your app and see if that actually is the case. I also recommend running the static analyzer to check for common memory errors.

Comment: How are you going back and forth between the 2 controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but here's a thought.  When you call this line:

```
[[self.topView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

It removes all of the subviews which declare `self.topView` as a superview.  The next line:

```
self.topView = nil
```

Doesn't remove the top view itself, but rather nil's your pointer to it.  Because views are retained by their superviews, this object will stick in memory until the view controller is removed and its view is released.

Comment: Thanks! After added `[self.topView removeFromSuperview];`, memory released properly.

Answer (score 0):

Check your variable declarations (weak, strong) to be sure that the topView object hasn't retain somewhere else.
Such as IBOutlet's usually declared with a **Weak** Key:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView * topView;
```